# How do I test a new git server?

Tags: git

I've just set up a git server, with Smart HTTP access, and I need to check that there aren't any problems before letting anyone else use it.

However, I know next to nothing about git itself. I've checked that I can `clone`, `fetch`, `pull`, and `push`, but that's it. Is there a better way to do this, short of learning git and setting up and using a large project?

I've checked the HTTP protocol documentation ([here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/gitprotocol-http.txt) or `man 5 gitprotocol-http`), and my initial reading is that I only need to check that two services exist: `git-upload-pack` and `git-receive-pack`. I can check that these exist with `curl`:

```
$ curl -i -raw https://example.com/git/test.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack | cat -v
HTTP/1.1 200 OK^M
...
Content-Type: application/x-git-receive-pack-advertisement^M
...
001f# service=git-receive-pack
000000b3e644099125769fc0fdc512f573367f3819d17437 refs/heads/master^@report-status report-status-v2 delete-refs side-band-64k quiet atomic ofs-delta object-format=sha1 agent=git/2.34.1
```

Can I assume that anything a git client will throw at me will work if I get reasonable output for `git-upload-pack` and `git-receive-pack`? What is a 'reasonable' output anyway? Any other tips for common problems in server setups that might be useful? Thanks.

Comment: Ask someone who knows it to test it for you. Or learn how to use it.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: then I'd be testing the client, not the server.